# why does twilio reject trigger another call attempt?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

when i use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Reject reason="busy" />
</Response>
```

and listen for changes in the callstatus with my python flask server with an handler like this

```
@app.route("/callstatus", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def statusChange():
    calldata = request.values

    print(calldata["CallSid"]+" : " + calldata["CallStatus"])

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    return str(resp)
```

I tend to get the a StatusCallbackEvent 2 times in a row, giving me a CallStatus of "busy"

further investigation showed that I also get a VoiceCallInEvent after rejecting the call.

it seems as if after a reject as well as a hang-up there is another call dispatched by the caller and then immediately rejected again.

Now I am unsure if use some part of the API wrong or this is normal behaviour or both.

I can catch this behaviour because the second call has another CallSID but I am wondering if there is another way to get around getting Double Triggers or if this might be connected to the German phone operators and not to twilio itself.

Testing in Germany from mobile as well as landline.

Comment: Is `<Reject>` the only TwiML you respond with to these calls? Nothing else before?

Comment: I just did a bit of a test here. A phone number pointing at a URL that only returned the TwiML to reject the call with the busy reason and a status callback URL that just logged the request and returned 200. I only received one webhook to the call endpoint and one webhook to the status endpoint. Is there anything different about your setup here?